# How to prevent Angular form having to emit twice before event is captured in parent component?

Tags: angular-material, angular-forms

I have an Angular application which contains a form that allows a user to increment a quantity.

- The form is loaded when a user clicks an "Add" button, and is prefilled with a quantity of 1.
- A FormControl object is passed into the form from the parent and when the customer increments/decrements the quantity, it is updated via patchValue and this **should** emit an event which can be captured in the parent using a subscription to valueChanges.
- **However** for a reason I cannot determine, the quantity must be incremented **twice** before the parent component subscription registers an event.
- Once the first event is registered, all subsequent increments/decrements work as expected.

[There is a minimal working StackBlitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wk9nnx?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Here is the parent component from the above example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Counter],
  template: `<h1>Counter</h1>
  <Counter [value]="1" [control]="qtyForm"></Counter>
  <p>Value from form emission:</p>
  <p>{{newQuantity}}</p>`,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  newQuantity!: number | null;
  qtyForm = new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.max(99)]);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateCustomQuantity();
  }
  updateCustomQuantity() {
    this.qtyForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((qty) => {
        this.newQuantity = qty;
      });
  }
}
```

and the child (Counter) component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Counter',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <p>Need to increment/decrement twice before form emits:</p>
    <button (click)="decrement()">Subtract</button>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [formControl]="control">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button (click)="increment()">Add</button>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => Counter),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Counter implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  formControlDirective!: FormControlDirective;
  currentValue!: number | null | undefined;
  @Input() value!: number;
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.control.patchValue(this.value, { emitEvent: false });
    this.currentValue = this.value;
  }
  
  increment() {
    const currentValue = this.control.value;
    this.control.patchValue(currentValue + 1);
  }

  decrement() {
    const currentValue = this.control.value;
    this.control.patchValue(currentValue - 1);
  }
...
}
```

I have to admit I'm a bit stumped by this. Removing emitEvent: false from ngOninit() has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be to change the `ngAfterViewInit` to a `ngOnInit` and it works fine, as to why the `ngAfterViewInit` is not firing on load is a mystery to me, maybe someone else can explain that, or you can raise a ticket in the angular github page!

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { Counter } from '../Counter';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Counter, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  template: `<h1>Counter</h1>
  <Counter [value]="0" [control]="qtyForm"></Counter>
  <p>Value from form emission:</p>
  <p>{{newQuantity}}</p>`,
})
export class App {
  newQuantity!: number | null;
  qtyForm = new FormControl(1, [Validators.required, Validators.max(99)]);

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('asdf');
    this.updateCustomQuantity();
  }

  updateCustomQuantity() {
    console.log(this.qtyForm.value);
    this.newQuantity = this.qtyForm.value;
    this.qtyForm.valueChanges.subscribe((qty) => {
      this.newQuantity = qty;
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j4v3wn)